# Разработка для Apple TV - с чего начать?

Tags: javascript, swift, tvos

Есть задача - запилить небольшое приложение для tvOS. С чего начать изучение разработки под эту платформу? Пытался найти старт гайды под это дело, а их почти нет. Не совсем понятно на чем разработка ведется: на Swift или JavaScript? Да и о самой ОС никакого представления нет.

Comment: [В документации все есть](https://developer.apple.com/documentation) и про темплейт [swiftui](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/app)

Answer (score 0):

Приложения для tvOS, как и для macOS, iOS, iPadOS пилятся на Objective-C или на Swift в среде Xcode, которая есть только для macOS. Можно начать с https://swiftbook.ru

Answer (score 0):

А если навыки свифта уже есть, то изучение можно начать с офф гайда

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241-CH12-SW1